# My ship command doesn't work with mentions

Tags: javascript, discord, arguments, discord.js

I am trying to make ship command, I have almost everything done but when I use it there are two problems:

1. It takes first half from both words (I want to take first half from the first word and second half from the second one)
2. When I mention 2 people then my bot doesn't respond

My code looks like this:

````
 function getRandomIntInclusive() {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
          }
        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Podaj pierwszy argument!")
        if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send("Podaj drugi argument!")

        if (args[0] || args[1]) {
            var FirstUser = args[0]
            var SecondUser = args[1]

            if (message.mentions.members.first()) {
                const FirstUserSliced = FirstUser.user.username.slice(0, FirstUser.user.username.length / 2)
                const SecondUserSliced = SecondUser.map(user => { return user.user.username.slice(user.user.username.length / 2) })
                const SecondUserName = SecondUser.map(user => { return user.user.username })
            } else if (FirstUser || SecondUser) {
                const FirstUserSliced = FirstUser.slice(0, FirstUser.length / 2)
                const SecondUserSliced = SecondUser.slice (SecondUser.lenght / 2, SecondUser.length / 2)
                const SecondUserName = FirstUserSliced + SecondUserSliced 
            

                const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Ship')
                .setDescription(`${SecondUserName}`)
                .addField(`Ocena shipu:`, `${getRandomIntInclusive()}%`)
                .setColor(0x0099ff)
              .setTimestamp()
              .setFooter(`${message.author.username}`);
                message.channel.send(embed)
            }
        }
    ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer your problems:

1.It takes first half from both words (I want to take first half from the first word and second half from the second one)

> In your code you have this row `slice(SecondUser.lenght / 2, SecondUser.length / 2)`, let's assume you wrote `lenght` here(StackOverflow), and what it does is it cuts the first half, otherwise if you had that typo it would notify you.

2. When I mention 2 people then my bot doesn't respond

> Because you have that if statement `if (message.mentions.members.first())` where it doesn't get into the MessageEmbed so if you mention someone it goes to the first if statement and can't send a message because there is no message.

I wrote an easier version of your's code so it's easier to understand.

```
function GetHalfText(first, second) {
    return first.substring(0, Math.floor(first.length / 2)) + second.substring(Math.floor(second.length / 2), second.length);
}
function Match(arg){
    return arg.match(/<@!?(\d{17,19})>/);
}
const {mentions, guild} = message
if(args.length < 2) return message.channel.send("You must enter two arguments")
const FirstArg = Match(args[0]) ? guild.members.cache.get(Match(args[0])[1]).user.username : args[0];
const SecondArg =  Match(args[1])|| guild.members.cache.get(Match(args[1])[1]).user.username || args[1];
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Ship')
                .setDescription(`${GetHalfText(FirstArg, SecondArg)}`)
                .addField(`Ocena shipu:`, `${getRandomIntInclusive()}%`)
                .setColor(0x0099ff)
              .setTimestamp()
              .setFooter(`${message.author.username}`);
                message.channel.send(embed)
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but next issue is that you can't use two arguments that aren't mentions using this command, still, it was helpful and I think I will be able to implement this to my code

Comment: Updated my answer see if does what you want

Comment: When I use your code no matter if I use mantions or normal text as arguments bot says "You must enter two arguments" (even if I enter 2 of them)

Comment: change `if(!args.length < 2) ` to `if(args.length < 2) `  I mistyped

Comment: When I type in args:
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
When I type in two mentions:
ReferenceError: FirstUser is not defined

About the first one I don't even know what that means
About the second one I thought of changing FirstUser to FirstArg but it wouldn't be able to take user's username from args (for example: m!ship 1234 5678) there wouldn't be any username to take, so it would still just work with mentions

Comment: Updated so your args will always be strings

Comment: The problem with args remains and when I use mentions then I get this error:
TypeError: second.substring is not a function